# How to fix display bugs on iphone 5 and 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, layout, ios-autolayout

I wanted to know how to have the same margins on all the iPhone ?
I would like the switches to be on the right side of the screen and not in the middle.
[image: iphone 7 screenshot]
[image: iphone 5 screenshot]

Comment: put it on a stack view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it with proper constraints

[image]

Comment: OK, I check "constrain to margins" ?

Comment: Make more readable, you need "trailing" constraint for Switch, and "leading" for Label